# Change the shape of body dynamically

Tags: box2d, andengine

I have a problem where i have a ballon which i need to continuously inflate and defalte in update method, I have tried to used setScaleCenter but it is not giving desired result.
Below is a code i am trying to make work

```
    scale += (float) ((dist-lastDist)/lastDist);
    Log.d("pinch","scale is "+scale);
    Log.d("pinch","change in scale is "+(float) ((lastDist-dist)/lastDist));
    player.setScaleCenter(scale, scale);
    player.setScale(scale);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a thing that Box2D does very well. If you're a confident programmer you can look into Maciej Matyka soft bodies and make something yourself...

Comment: You say it is not giving the desired result - what result is it having?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that `player` is of type `Sprite`. You are changing the sprite size and center of the scaling. That has no effect on the physics body.

You can try using the `setRadius()` method from the `Shape` class. Not sure if that works for every `Shape`, but it does work for circle shapes. If you are creating circle bodies like this:

```
Body b = PhysicsFactory(physicsWorld, player, bodyType, fixture);
```

Try:

```
b.getFixtureList().get(0).getShape().setRadius(newRadius);
```